# Webgl supported but not enabled on Nexus 7

Tags: android, google-chrome, webgl, nexus-7

I have been trying to write an Android application which uses a Three.js WebGL renderer. For some reason, constructing the WebGL renderer caused an error on my Nexus 7, and after further investigation, I discovered that my device didn't seem to do get along with anything WebGL-related at all, and even Chrome didn't work with WebGL. When I visited get.webgl.org, it told me that WebGL seemed to be supported on my device, but wasn't enabled. I did some more research and found advice from several sources that told me that Nexus 7's do support WebGL, and that I should go to chrome://flags and select "Enable WebGL". Unfortunately, when I went to chrome://flags, there was no Enable WebGL option. Out of desperation, I tried enabling "WebGL 2.0 Prototype" and "WebGl draft extensions", hoping that this would fix the problem. Instead, Chrome ended up crashing and I ultimately had to reinstall the chrome app to get it working again. Anyway, the point is: *What can I do to get WebGL working on my Nexus 7?*

Answer (score 1):

Firefox can render WebGL content on Nexus 7

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the software rendering list. Go to `chrome://flags` and `Enable` the `Override software rendering list`. It will solve the problem if your GPU is blacklisted by chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to solve the problem. Is there anything else I could try?